# Why is JS code inside html <button> tag so slow compared to external JS script file?

Tags: javascript, html

I know that using `<button onclick="some js code here">` and writing JS directly into HTML is really bad practice. But it's bugging me why is it so slow compared to running included JavaScript file (for example when I run a function from the outer file it is about 100x faster). Seems like the same code but the execution time is greatly different.

Here you have an example:

```js
var i, x = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  x += Math.random() * 10
};

document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = x;

function loop() {
  var x = 0;
  
  for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    x += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
  };
  
  document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="value">value</h1>

<button onclick="var i, x = 0; for(i=0;i<1000000;i++){x += Math.floor(Math.random()*10)}; document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = x; ">test speed</button>

<button onclick="loop()">test speed 2</button>
```

"test speed" and "test speed 2" buttons have identical code to run but the second button runs it much faster (the one that runs it from outer js file).

Comment: Did you measure the 100x faster execution? Do you have an example running?

Comment: can you prove this with a https://jsperf.com/ example?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/aa5uu0sc/1/ - "test speed" and "test speed 2" buttons have identical code to run but the second button runs it much faster (the one that runs it from outer js file)

Comment: there *might* be merit to the issue the question here is trying to describe.  however, without any code to test against, and without any demonstrated proofs of the speed difference, any answer would just be conjecture.

Comment: Also, in IE 11, both buttons on the sample fiddle perform approximately similar.

Answer (score 0):

Most JS engines are able to optimize for predefined functions, which is why it is so much faster.  When you don't define your functions up front, it becomes much harder for browsers to optimize the JS execution.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why it should be harder to optimize the code in the button.

I would guess instead that the JavaScript engine just does not keep track of the code in the button. After all the JavaScript engine and the DOM engine code are separate.

That would mean that the JavaScript has to parse and optimize it for every button click since it does not know if it has changed since the last run.

Of course the people coding the browser could fix this, but why should they? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

code string set in onclick requires internal `eval` which causes the slowness.
Try wrap the code inside loop() function with eval and you will get the same result as it is in onclick attribute